# How to prevent JPA deleteByID() from deleting parent when deleting a child?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I've got a spring mvc application in which users book meeting rooms. When I try to delete a booking by using deleteById(), the user that belongs to the booking is also deleted. How do I prevent this?

Booking object:

```
package spe_booker.models;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Date;
@Entity
public class Booking {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private Date startDateTime;
    @NotNull
    private Date endDateTime;
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Room room;
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;
    private Date creationDate;

    public Booking() {  }
    ...getters and setters...
```

User object:

```
package spe_booker.models;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
    private String username;
    String name;
    private String password;
    private String faculty;
    private String role;
    private Boolean blacklisted;
    @Column(name = "enabled")
    public int enabled;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Booking> bookings = new ArrayList<>();
    ...getters and setters...
```

Booking repository:

```
package spe_booker.Repositorys;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import spe_booker.models.Booking;
import spe_booker.models.User;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface BookingRepository extends CrudRepository<Booking, Long> {
    List<Booking> findAll();
    List<Booking> findBookingsByUser(User user);
}
```

The delete call:

```
bookingRepository.deleteById(id);
```

Comment: And what `deleteById(id)` method does? Because you have Id in both Entities

Comment: Well you have `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) private User user;` so the deletion of a `Booking` entity will be cascaded to the user as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the cascade of

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private User user;
```

to the appropriate values. Do you change a user and then save a booking and a user at the same time? Do you create bookings with users at the same time? If you can answer these questions with "no", you might just remove `(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` at all. And you should ask yourself why the cascades are present in the first place!

Comment: This was it thanks so much. After your comment I had a google and realised that I don't actually need cascade. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`CascadeType.ALL` forces JPA to cascade all operations (persisting, removing, updating....). That means when you delete/update a booking, it willl delete/update the **Room** and **User** objects too